# How can I limit the number of objects that the user can drag and drop to a specific layout?

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed a card sort app that the user can drag and drop cards on the screen according to the code here-
[drag and drop code](https://www.androhub.com/android-drag-and-drop/)

how can I limit the number of objects that can be dragged to a specific layout?
(i would like to limit the number of objects to only one for each layout)

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though it is in the `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` where the view is added to the new parent. So when that happens you can simply check if the view your adding it to already has a certain number of children:

Change this:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

    ...

    View v = (View) event.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    owner.removeView(v);//remove the dragged view
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) view;
    container.addView(v);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to this:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

    ...

    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) view;
    if (container.getChildCount() < 1) { // only move the view if the container has no kids
        View v = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        owner.removeView(v);
        container.addView(v);
    }
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: @tamariwolfman Glad I could help, please remember to select and up vote answers that help you :)